# How to install Metamask on Chrome in Android?

Tags: metamask, android

**Questions.**
How to install Metamask on Chrome in Android?
or
How to use Metamask in Android?

**Description:**

- I followed the link metamask.io
- I tried Get Chrome Extension.
- The site redirected me to -  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metamask/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn?hl=en
- I clicked Install.
- Result: the Metamask browser is installed.

**Used by:**
Android
Model - Mi PAD 3
Android Version - 7.0 NRD90M
MIUI Version - MIUI 8.3 by xiaomi.eu 7.5.25
Browser - Chrome

**Metamask browser**
[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for Android.

Answer (score 4):

You can also download the metamask application from the play store..

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.metamask&hl=en

Comment: This is correct. Chrome mobile does not support addons, so MetaMask Mobile is a separate application.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa thanks for my first upvote on ethereum.stack xD

Comment: I need to make your score go up, so you can start upvoting yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Kiwi Browser. Kiwi Browser support MetaMask plugin.

Answer (score 1):

As the others mentioned, this does not work. With WalletConnect you can sign tx from the metamask app on your phone on other browsers. Follow the official metamask docs for more informations: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/mobile-best-practices.html#using-walletconnect

If you're trying to develop or debug an app on your metamask mobile browser follow the description on the metamask docs: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/mobile-best-practices.html#website-testing-and-debugging